# Initializing 1 more int causes a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, coredump

I'm using this code to read a file through piping to child processes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int numchild;
int i, j, len, fpos=0, val, count=0, total=0, alltotal=0;
pid_t pid;
int nums = 1000;
FILE * file;

printf("How many children to use: ");
scanf("%d", &numchild);
printf("\nWill use %d child process(es).\n", numchild);

int fd[2*numchild][2]; //parent+child pipe

// create all pipes
for (i=0; i<2*numchild; i++)
{
    pipe(fd[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<numchild; i++)
{
    if((pid = fork()) == 0) // child process
    {
        pid = getpid();

        // read from parent
        len = read(fd[i][0], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));
        if (len > 0)
        {
            file = fopen("file1.dat", "r");
            fseek (file, fpos, SEEK_SET);
            count = 0;
            total = 0;

            printf("Child(%d): Recieved position: %d\n", pid, fpos);

            // read from file starting at fpos
            // add values read to a total value
            while (count < (nums/numchild))
            {
                fscanf(file, "%i", &val);
                total += val;
                count++;
            }
            //write to parent
            write(fd[i+numchild][1], &total, sizeof(total));
            printf("Child(%d): Sent %d to parent.\n", pid, total);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Child(%d): Error with len\n", pid);
        }

        _exit;
    }

    // parent process
    pid = getpid();

    fpos = ((i*nums*5)/numchild); // 5 is the offset of the file values

    // write to child process
    printf("Parent(%d): Sending file position to child\n", pid);
    write(fd[i][1], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));

    // wait for child responce
    len = read(fd[i+numchild][0], &total, sizeof(total));
    if (len > 0)
    {
        printf("Parent(%d): Recieved %d from child.\n", pid, total);
        alltotal += total;
        printf("Parent(%d): Total: %d\n", pid, alltotal);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Parent(%d): Error with len\n", pid);
    }
}
}
```

I've found that i get a segmentation error due to initializing `alltotal=0` at the top of the code.  A previous iteration of editing allowed the code to execute; now after adding `alltotal`, it does not work.

---

**EDIT:**

I've done some debugging, though I'm not sure what it means to me

```
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/tames/Desktop/project1_data/a.out

Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x0000000000400894 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe998) at finalSum.c:14
14              printf("How many children to use: ");
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000000000400894 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe998) at finalSum.c:14
(gdb) frame 0
#0  0x0000000000400894 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe998) at finalSum.c:14
14              printf("How many children to use: ");
(gdb)
```

---

Would using up too much memory cause an error like this?

Thank you.
-Tom

Comment: My spidey-senses are all a-tingling from the UB. `int fd[2*numchild][2]`

Comment: In C++, variable-length arays are not supported.

Comment: This looks like entirely C. The tag is probably wrong.

Comment: `int numchild;`
`int fd[2*numchild][2];` 
Does not look too healthy...

Comment: Hey all, that line changed has been changed and it seems to have worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
int fd[2*numchild][2];
```

When you perform this declaration, `numchild` contains a garbage value. `numchild` needs to be initialized before you create the array. Move that line to after the `scanf`.